# Java Inner Classes and HashMaps

Tags: java, hashmap, inner-classes

So I am working on a Java project, and one of my classes uses inner nested classes (the TypesOfQuestions) and when I try to add a question from the inner class to the HashMap, it doesn't let me, and I'm not sure why.

```
public abstract class TypesOfQuestions {

Map<String, Double> scores = new TreeMap<String, Double>();
String text;
double points;

public TypesOfQuestions(String text, double points) {

}


public static class TrueFalse extends TypesOfQuestions {
    public TrueFalse(String text, double points, boolean answer) {
        super(text, points);
    }
}
```

And the other class is Exam, which

```
public class Exam {
private String x;
private Map<Integer, Questions> q;

public HoldExam(String x) {
    q = new HashMap<Integer, Questions>();
    this.x = x;
}

public void addTrueFalseQuestion(int questionNumber, String text, 
                                 double points, boolean answer){
    q.put(questionNumber, new TrueFalse (text, points, answer));

}
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different things, but I keep getting errors, for this one I got

```
No enclosing instance of type TypesOfQuestions is accessible. 
Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type TypesOfQuestions 
(e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of TypesOfQuestions).
```

Anndddd I have no idea what to do!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TrueFalse` should probably be `static`, as it's not associated with an outer instance of `TypesOfQuestions`; it *is* a `TypesOfQuestions`.

Comment: Oh no!  wait, so I changed it to static like you said and it fixed the error until I tried to hit save, and then the error came back.  Same error too.

Comment: Where is the `Questions` class defined here?  We don't have a definition for `Questions`.

Comment: Sorry, Questions should be TypesOfQuestions, I just didn't type it in right.  Also, eclipse seems to accept it and then not accept it... it's giving me the error sometimes, and then not other times... but I'm not changing any of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Change your nested class to be static, so that it doesn't require an implicit reference to the outer class.

```
    public static class TrueFalse extends TypesOfQuestions { ... }
```

Inner classes *without* the static qualifier are allowed to access the members of the outer class. This requires that they hold an implicit reference to the outer class.